# LockBox Stream read error, RSA

Tags: delphi, encryption, lockbox-3

I'm loading a RSA key from a stream and getting an "Stream Read" error? What's the first thing I should try to get my code working?

Comment: You post code, but does that have anything to do with the question you are asking? What code causes the error?

Comment: I can post that code, which is just a standard lockbox rsa encryption setup, but it is identical to a functional piece with a different key from elsewhere in the project, so I'm pretty sure the problem isn't there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bit of a wild guess, but this can happen if the stream's position is not reset to 0 when you try to read from the stream, after having written to it. Try setting

```
SigStore.Position := 0;
```

immediately before using the stream to encrypt.